# Highstock display multiple series with wrong scale on yAxis so lines are stacked randomly

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I have a Highstock chart displaying 3 data series. The series have the correct values but the line with higher values is not displayed above the other two, but between them, and this changes randomly.

Here you can see three spots of the same chart:
[spot one](https://postimg.cc/QHN3hqG3) [spot two](https://postimg.cc/fktd5YgM) [spot three](https://postimg.cc/4nD90nrV)

I've tried changing the data series, changing the period. This only happens when I have three data series. I have charts with two and four data series and they work well.

This is the chart config that I'm using.

```
Highcharts.stockChart(container, {
        chart:{
            zoomType: 'x',
            events: {
                load: updateLegendLabel
            }
        },
        title: {
            text: graficoData.nombre
        },

        credits: {
            enabled: false
        },
        exporting: {
            buttons: {
                contextButton: {
                    menuItems: buttons
                }
            }
        },

        rangeSelector: {
            enabled: showRangeSelectors,
            buttons: [
            {
                type: 'day',
                count: 1,
                text: '1d'
            }, {
                type: 'month',
                count: 1,
                text: '1m'
            }, {
                type: 'month',
                count: 3,
                text: '3m'
            },  {
                type: 'all',
                text: 'Todo'
            }],
            buttonTheme: {
                width: 60
            },
            selected: 2
        },

        xAxis: {
            events: {
                afterSetExtremes: updateLegendLabel
            }
        },
        yAxis: {
            resize: {
                enabled: true
            },
        },

        plotOptions: {
            series: {
                compare: 'percent',
                showInNavigator: true
            }
        },
        navigator: {
            height: 30,
            margin: 2
        },
        tooltip: {
            pointFormat: '<span style="color:{series.color}">{series.name}</span>: <b>{point.y}</b> <br/>',
            valueDecimals: 2,
            split: true,
            valueSuffix:' ' + unidad
        },
        responsive: {
            rules: [{
                condition: {
                    maxHeight: '100%'
                },
                chartOptions: {
                    rangeSelector: {
                        inputEnabled: false
                    }
                }
            }]
        },

        series: series
    });
```

I expect that when the yAxis value is higher, the line get displayed above, and when the value is lower the line get displayed below, since they share the same scale.
Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: Hi @Denis, Could you reproduce that issue in some online code editor? In this simple example: http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/3xykme4q/ everything works.